# Updating nested object property mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, updates

I have a database such as :

[image]

I need to update the property : `leadType` of a particular object based on it's `_id` as per user request, say with `id: 5e8333cf4f19264d809b4e8c`.

I used the following query, but it eventually return me the empty array:

```
exports.change_lead_action = (req, res, next) => {
  let lead_obj_id = req.body.leadObjId;

  Lead.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(lead_obj_id) },
    { leads: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.body.leadId }}}, {leadType: req.body.leadType}, (err, lead) => {
      console.log('updated', lead)
    }
  )
```

I am not sure, where I am going wrong.

I also tried using `Lead.find()` query. Although that returned me the result I required but I couldn't find the way to update the property out of the returned result:

```
{
    "message": "data found",
    "lead": [
        {
            "_id": "5e8333cf4f19264d809b4e8e",
            "leads": [
                {
                    "education": {
                        "school": "happy kids corner",
                        "graduation": "some school"
                    },
                    "currentPosition": {
                        "title": "Salesforce developer",
                        "description": "Full stack programmer",
                        "joiningDate": "16 december 2019",
                        "endDate": "currently working",
                        "employmentType": "full-time",
                        "industry": "information technology"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "state": "delhi",
                        "country": "india"
                    },
                    "leadType": "all",
                    "name": "Ben",
                    "mobile": 1524524678,
                    "_id": "5e8333cf4f19264d809b4e8c"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your query is wrong. Here are the docs for [Mongoose findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html).

As per them, the first parameter is the query, second be the update command.

So you need to structure it like:

```
  Lead.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
       _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(lead_obj_id),
       leads: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.body.leadId }}
    },
    {leadType: req.body.leadType}, (err, lead) => {
      console.log('updated', lead)
    }
```

Comment: Oh it was a big mistake. Glad you pointed out. I changed the syntax but it's still returning me null value and no updation in the db.

Comment: you need to give more information, like how the leadId looks like. Have you tried wrapping it with mongoose ObjectId? Also read the documentation. you'll find your issue.

Comment: I did look around with the documentation. I need to update the leadType of the particular object using it's id. But it's not working. Please help to figure this out